# Is this proof of power rule for derivatives valid

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

I recently came up with the following proof of the power rule $(x^p)'=px^{p-1}$:

> Let $y=x^p$. Then $\ln {y}=p\ln x$, and by chain rule:
>   $$ \frac{y'}{y}=p\frac{1}{x}$$
>   so $y'=(x^p)'=p\frac{y}{x}=\frac{x^p}{x}=px^{p-1}$

Is this proof *mathematically rigorous*, or does it need additional clarification?

Comment: what is $p$? a real number? then must be $$x>0$$

Comment: the proof is ok, you must say something about the variables

Comment: What is it that you want to prove? the power rule (I'm assuming that $p$ is a positive integer—If $p$ is a negative integer it's similar with a different domain, and if $p$ is not an integer then adapt the domain too) states: the function $f:x\mapsto x^p$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and moreover $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ f'(x)=p x^{p-1}$. Your proof only shows the moreover part (you take for granted that $f$ is differentiable), and is only valid on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

You can also use that $$x^{\alpha}=e^{\alpha\ln(x)}$$ and use the chain rule

Comment: But again, this doesn't work for $x\le 0$ - is there any way we could apply my idea to this case?

Comment: for $$(-x)^n$$ you can use $$(-1)^n \dot x^n$$ if $n$ is a integer number

Comment: @MightyPython More to the point, $x^\alpha$ is a really badly behaved function in the region $x<0$, essentially because complex numbers pop up all over the place. The power rule still holds where it makes sense, though.

Answer (score 0):

This proof is valid, and a proof of this kind is necessary if arbitrary exponents $p\in{\mathbb R}$ are at stake. The usual proof using induction or the binomial theorem only works for integer exponents $n\geq0$, and then via the quotient rule for negative integers $n$.